# how to implement OSPF using Ns-2

Tags: implementation, ns2, ospf

I am new in this field.Please help me to implement open shortest path first(OSPF) in ns2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download OSPF patch file for ns2 from following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ospf4ns/

hope it helps

Comment: hello naveen i am getting error in setting ospf parameters..the error is in this line "Agent/rtProto/OSPF set helloInterval 1"

Comment: What about NS3 using Python.